# how to convert this string into two dimensional array using java

Tags: java

I have text file as

```
    0B85     61
    0B86     6161
    0B86     41
    0B87     69
    0B88     6969
    0B88     49
    0B89     75
    0B8A     7575
    0B8F     6565
```

I want to write this string into two dimensional array. (i.e) `String read[0][0]=0B85` and `String read[0][1]=61`.
Please suggest any idea to do this using java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: yeah, just write it and if you have any problem, post the problem. It is as simple and easy as a small homework

Answer (score 6):

Something like this works:

```
String s = "0B85 61 0B86 6161 0B86 41 0B87 69 0B88"
    + " 6969 0B88 49 0B89 75 0B8A 7575 0B8F 6565";
String[] parts = s.split(" ");
String[][] table = new String[parts.length / 2][2];
for (int i = 0, r = 0; r < table.length; r++) {
    table[r][0] = parts[i++];
    table[r][1] = parts[i++];
}
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(table));
// prints "[[0B85, 61], [0B86, 6161], [0B86, 41], [0B87, 69],
//   [0B88, 6969], [0B88, 49], [0B89, 75], [0B8A, 7575], [0B8F, 6565]]
```

Essentially you `split(" ")` the long string into parts, then arrange the parts into a 2 column `String[][] table`.

That said, the best solution for this would be to have a `Entry` class of some sort for each row, and have a `List<Entry>` instead of a `String[][]`.

---

> *NOTE: Was thrown off by formatting, keeping above, but following is what is needed*

If you have `columns.txt` containing the following:

```
    0B85     61
    0B86     6161
    0B86     41
    0B87     69
    0B88     6969
    0B88     49
    0B89     75
    0B8A     7575
    0B8F     6565
```

Then you can use the following to arrange them into 2 columns `String[][]`:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
//...

    List<String[]> entries = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("columns.txt"));
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        entries.add(new String[] { sc.next(), sc.next() });
    }
    String[][] table = entries.toArray(new String[0][]);
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(table));
```

I will reiterate that a `List<Entry>` is much better than a `String[][]`, though.

#### See also

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 25: Prefer lists to arrays*
- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 50: Avoid strings where other types are more appropriate*

Answer (score 0):

Something like (Pseudo code):

```
parts = yourData.split()
out = new String[ parts.length/2 ][2];
int j=0;
for i=0, i < parts.length -1, i+2:
  out[j][0] =  parts[i]
  out[j][1] = parts[i+1] 
  j++
```